# undefined reference to `WinMain@16' in C++ app, with Code::Blocks

Tags: c++, linker, codeblocks

I just made a small program to tests some differences between java and C++ inheritance. It compiles but I get a problem when linking:

```
mingw32-g++.exe  -o bin\Release\Tests2.exe obj\Release\Exec.o   -s -lmingw32  
c:/program files/codeblocks/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.7.1/../../../libmingw32.a(main.o):main.c:(.text.startup+0xa7): undefined reference to `WinMain@16'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Process terminated with status 1 (0 minutes, 0 seconds)
1 errors, 0 warnings (0 minutes, 0 seconds)
```

I've no ides where it comes from. I'm compiling a console app, not a GUI app, plus my main method is well formed:

```
class Exec{

public:
    int main( int argc, const char* argv[] ){
        Operation* op1=new Operation("add");
        Operation* op2=new Operation("rest");
    MyExtend* ext=new MyExtend(6,4, op1);
    MyExtend* ext2=new MyExtend(6,4, op2);
    cout << ext->getSum()->getValue() << endl;
    cout << ext2->getRest()->getValue() << endl;
    return 0;
}

};
```

I tried adding -lmingw32 but it doesn't work either (it shouldn't be added anyway). All the answers I found are referencing the GUI and main problem, but this is not the case. Any ideas?

All the best.

Comment: You have no `main` function to run when the program starts.

Comment: C++ is different from Java, `main()` must be outside a class

Comment: Arg! Right. It was so simple. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C++, main function is the entrance of the program, you should write it separately, not in the class.

Answer (score 0):

The bigest difference of java and cplusplus is you must write program entry by your self and also it is must c compatiple,so main is needed ,winmain is windows special, check your link flags is there a windows subsystem link flags ,chang it to console,it will be ok then.